# No puedo detectar palabras desde fichero con espacios en python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando programar un bot que detecta x palabra dentro del archivo **.txt**, todo funciona perfectamente pero a la hora de escribir algun nombre con espacio por ejemplo:

```
A Sweaty Dog
```

No me lo detecta cómo valido

[image]

Deberia de detectarmelo de color verde el embed

Un ejemplo cómo deberia de funcionar:

[image]

Este es el código qué estoy usando:

```
@bot.command()
async def bots(ctx,   *, nombre):
    #await ctx.message.delete()
    encontrado = False
    
    
    embed=discord.Embed(description=f"**{nombre}** no es un bot de FORTNITE<:NoRobot:1028593518207311952>", color=0xff0000) #EMBED DE COLOR ROJO
    embed.set_author(name=f"{nombre}", icon_url='https://i.imgur.com/tFXTG2K.png')
    
    with open('bots.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        for line in f:
            if nombre in line.split():
                encontrado = True
                break;
    if encontrado:
        
        embed=discord.Embed(description=f"**{nombre}** Es un bot de FORTNITE<:BotFortnite:1028593519964737586>", color=0x37ff00) #EMBED DE COLOR VERDE

        embed.set_author(name=f"{nombre}", icon_url='https://i.imgur.com/giQyDd3.png')
        
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Muchas gracias antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nota: estoy asumiendo que el txt es el nombre de un bot por cada linea. Si no es así, te recomiendo editar la pregunta y mostrar el txt.

#### Explicación

Lo que hace tu código en cada linea del txt es separar la linea usando grupos de espacios y saltos de linea como separador. Eso significa que si una de las lineas del txt es `A Sweaty Dog` se convierte en `["A", "Sweaty", "Dog", ""]` (la ultima cadena vacía es por que cuando iteras sobre un archivo, este incluye el salto de linea al final de la linea).
Y claro, `A Sweaty Dog` no va a estar contenido en esa lista.

En cambio, si nombre no tiene espacios, entonces dicha variable podría estar presente dentro de una de las listas. Por ejemplo si es "A", va a estar presente en una lista como ["A"] o ["A", "Sweaty", "Dog"].

#### Solución

NO separes la linea con split. En su lugar utiliza el método strip sin argumentos. Esto elimina todo lo que sea espacios y saltos de linea alrededor de la cadena (si es que existen). Y luego comparas si la linea es igual al nombre. Nota: esto es case-sensitive (o sea, `"A Sweaty Dog" != "a sweaty dog"`), si quieres evitar esto, usa el método lower en ambos lados de la expresión. Esto pasará a minusculas ambas cadenas.

```
if nombre.lower() == line.strip().lower()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si era eso

Comment: De nada juan c:

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pase es que `split()` separa por espaciones. Si venía el nombre buscado (*a sweaty dog*) dentro del texto, lo vas a separar en tres elementos (`'a', 'sweaty', 'dog'`), ninguno de los cuales es igual al nombre completo.

*Solución*

Usa el operador `in`, que te dice si un texto está dentro de otro. La comparación es *case sensitive*, asi que mejor convertir todo a minúsculas antes de comparar.

```
if nombre.lower() in texto:
    print("Si está")
```

#### Demo

```
nombre = "La Mona Jacinta"
texto = "la mona jacinta se ha puesto una cinta"

if nombre.lower() in texto:
    print("Si está")
```

produce:

```
Si está

Process finished with exit code
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.